# VBA Run-Time Error When Trying to set cell value to forumla

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to set the cell value to a formula when the column header matches a certain value. I'm getting a 1004 error and I believe this is due to my variable being set to a range and I'm setting it to a string value.

How do I correct the line "Cell.Formula = Formula_1" to allow the formula to be inserted?

```
Public Function WorksheetFormula(ByVal target As Range, ColumnHeader As String, formula_1 As String, columnFormula As String, cell As Range)

columnFormula = target.Offset((14 - target.Row), 0).Value

If columnFormula = "% Discount" Then
           formula_1 = "=IFERROR((GETPIVOTDATA(""Max of ""&INDIRECT((ADDRESS(14,COLUMN()))),'Database1 PivotTable'!$A$1," & _
           """KEY"",LEFT(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""B"",SUM(ROW()-1))),4)&CurrentHFMFamily&(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),-(SUM(ROW()-(6))),-(MOD(COLUMN()+1,4))))" & _
           "&CurrentYear,""PRODUCT"",CurrentHFMFamily,""PROGRAM"",LEFT(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""B"",SUM(ROW()-1))),4)," & _
           """CUSTOMERSEG"",CurrentCustomerSegment,""MONTH"",(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),-(SUM(ROW()-(6))),-(MOD(COLUMN()+1,4)))),""YEAR"",CurrentYear)),"")"

        ElseIf columnFormula = "% Take" Then
            formula_1 = "=IFERROR((GETPIVOTDATA(""Max of ""&INDIRECT((ADDRESS(14,COLUMN()))),'Database1 PivotTable'!$A$1," & _
            """KEY"",LEFT(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""B"",SUM(ROW()-1))),4)&CurrentHFMFamily&(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),-(SUM(ROW()-(6))),-(MOD(COLUMN()+1,4))))" & _
            "&CurrentYear,""PRODUCT"",CurrentHFMFamily,""PROGRAM"",LEFT(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""B"",SUM(ROW()-1))),4)," & _
            """CUSTOMERSEG"",CurrentCustomerSegment,""MONTH"",(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),-(SUM(ROW()-(6))),-(MOD(COLUMN()+1,4)))),""YEAR"",CurrentYear)),"")"

        ElseIf columnFormula = "Dollars" Then
            formula_1 = "=PRODUCT((OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),-(SUM(ROW()-(8))),(MOD(COLUMN()+1,4)))),(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,1))," & _
            "(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,2)))"

End If
Debug.Print columnFormula
Debug.Print formula_1
cell.Formula = formula_1
End Function
```

Comment: Are you going to do this for a whole range of data?  Why not make this a `Sub Function()` and use a `For...Next` Loop to go through all the rows and output the correct formula.  Also, I would suggest using a `Select... Case` to clean up your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Function is named `WorksheetFormula` try replacing `cell.Formula = formula_1` with `WorksheetFormula = formula_1`

```
    Public Function WorksheetFormula(ByVal target As Range, ColumnHeader As String, formula_1 As String, columnFormula As String, cell As Range)

    columnFormula = target.Offset((14 - target.Row), 0).Value

        Select Case collumnFormula    
            Case "% Discount"
               formula_1 = "=IFERROR((GETPIVOTDATA(""Max of ""&INDIRECT((ADDRESS(14,COLUMN()))),'Database1 PivotTable'!$A$1," & _
               """KEY"",LEFT(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""B"",SUM(ROW()-1))),4)&CurrentHFMFamily&(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),-(SUM(ROW()-(6))),-(MOD(COLUMN()+1,4))))" & _
               "&CurrentYear,""PRODUCT"",CurrentHFMFamily,""PROGRAM"",LEFT(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""B"",SUM(ROW()-1))),4)," & _
               """CUSTOMERSEG"",CurrentCustomerSegment,""MONTH"",(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),-(SUM(ROW()-(6))),-(MOD(COLUMN()+1,4)))),""YEAR"",CurrentYear)),"")"

            Case "% Take"
                formula_1 = "=IFERROR((GETPIVOTDATA(""Max of ""&INDIRECT((ADDRESS(14,COLUMN()))),'Database1 PivotTable'!$A$1," & _
                """KEY"",LEFT(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""B"",SUM(ROW()-1))),4)&CurrentHFMFamily&(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),-(SUM(ROW()-(6))),-(MOD(COLUMN()+1,4))))" & _
                "&CurrentYear,""PRODUCT"",CurrentHFMFamily,""PROGRAM"",LEFT(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(""B"",SUM(ROW()-1))),4)," & _
                """CUSTOMERSEG"",CurrentCustomerSegment,""MONTH"",(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),-(SUM(ROW()-(6))),-(MOD(COLUMN()+1,4)))),""YEAR"",CurrentYear)),"")"

            Case "Dollars"
                formula_1 = "=PRODUCT((OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),-(SUM(ROW()-(8))),(MOD(COLUMN()+1,4)))),(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,1))," & _
                "(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())),0,2)))"

            Case Else
                formula_1 = "Error"
    End Select
    Debug.Print columnFormula
    Debug.Print formula_1
    WorksheetFormula = formula_1
    End Function
```